# How to get matchedId or upsertedId with findOneAndUpdate or updateOne in MongoDB in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

For both of those functions `upsert` is set to `true`.

So `updateOne` returns `upsertedId` if no document matched the query, but if one document matches it does not return the id of the document that did (only `matchedCount` = 1).

And `findOneAndUpdate` with the `newDocument` option set to `true` will return the id of the updated document if it already exists, but if it does not it will return a `lastErrorObject` which contains the id of the upserted document but I do not like that it is an error.

I'd like to update a document if it already exists or create a new one if it does not, and retrieve the id of the updated/created document without it being in an error object. Is it possible with a single function?

Answer (score 0):

So for `findOneAndUpdate` options `returnNewDocument = true` and `returnDocument = "after"` behave differently despite `returnDocument` supposedly being an alternative to `returnNewDocument`.

With `returnDocument = "after"`, `findOneAndUpdate` will return an object that contains the document no matter if it is upserted or updated (so `result.value._id` will always give the id of the document).